# Predefined capacity when marshalling a List<> in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, list, marshalling

I am marshalling a List using WCF and an 'ref' parameter and I want to be able to set the capacity.

Some background. I am marshalling 2 List's using ref so that the calling function can determine which List it is interested in by initialising prior to the call.

Thus a quick test for null enables the service to do something with the list. This all works fine.

But I thought; I know there is going to be 100~ items in the list so setting an initial capacity is a good idea but when I do so in the calling function it is set back to 0 in the WCF service.

Any clues?

Thanks muchly.

EDIT: Thinking about it - this does make an enormous amount of sense does it. Any allocated resources from setting an initial capacity would have to be (wastefully) marshalled and then rehydrated/allocated.

I think a second parameter with a size or just hard coding it is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF passes all data by value. It never passes values by reference. Collections are transfefred as arrays so no additional information except contained data are transferred. Parameters marked as `ref` and `out` only defines which direction is the parameter transfered and also instruct proxy to fill existing instance with deserialized data (in case of `ref`).

If you want to transfer some information like capacity you must transfer it in separate parameter and use it in service to limit number of returned data.